# Is it possible to determine whether a method was called from inside or outside of a class?

Tags: php, oop

Example code:

```
class MyClass {
    function echo_msg {
        echo // now what...
    }

    function echo_from_inside {
        $this->echo_msg()
    }
}

result should be:

$my_instance = new MyClass();
$my_instance->echo_msg(); // I was called from OUTside
$my_instance->echo_from_inside(); // I was called from INside
```

Comment: Most likely not, which brings us to the question: *Why* do you need this? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I need to sanitize input variables if method is called from outside class but don't need to do it from inside where am safe.

Comment: In this case, @dnagirl has the best answer imo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be easier, rather than detecting from whence the function was called, to wrap a private function with a public one. Like so:

```
class MyClass{
  private function myob(){
    //do something
  }

  public function echo_msg(){
    $this->myob();
    //do other stuff like set a flag since it was a public call
  }

  private function foo(){ //some other internal function
    //do stuff and call myob
    $this->myob();
  }
}

$obj=new MyClass();
$obj->echo_msg();//get output
$obj->myob();  //throws error because method is private
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try and get the caller of your method:

```
$trace = debug_backtrace();
$caller = array_shift($trace);
echo 'called by '.$caller['function']
echo 'called by '.$caller['class']
```

this should work for you.

Comment: Never knew about `debug_backtrace();`, +1 for you

Comment: @GWW: this is not the full implementation, just the mechanism that will allow it. In fact, I think that the code above is just a testbed/sampler for the functionality the asker is interested to.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an optional parameter like such:

```
function echo_msg($ins=false) {
        if($ins){/*called from inside*/}else{/*called from outside*/}
        echo // now what...
    }
```

and leave that last. If you are calling it from inside the class, pass it `true`, otherwise pass nothing!

Comment: this is just way too easy to fool, I wouldn't rely on it.